# Unable to Retrieve Updated Data from MongoDB in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java

```
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I have MongoDB as the database backend. In my application, I have two entities: movie and reviews. Each movie can have multiple reviews associated with it.
```

I have implemented functionality to create a new review for a movie, and upon creation, I'm updating the reviewIds array in the respective movie document in MongoDB. The creation and updating processes seem to be working fine, as I can see the updates in the logs.

However, when I try to retrieve the movie data using a GET request after adding a new review, the reviewIds array in the movie object returned by the API remains empty, even though it should contain the newly added review ID.

I've verified that the review is successfully created and the movie document is updated with the new review ID in MongoDB. However, when fetching the movie data using Spring Data MongoDB, the reviewIds array is empty.

Here's an overview of my code:

I have a movie entity with fields such as imdbId, title, reviewIds, etc.
I have a reviews entity with fields like id, body, etc.
I have implemented a ReviewService class to create and update reviews, and a MovieService class to fetch movie data.
I have a MovieController class to handle HTTP requests for fetching movies.
I suspect there might be an issue with the way I'm retrieving the data or with the mapping between entities and MongoDB documents.

Could someone please help me understand why the reviewIds array is empty when fetching movie data, even though it's updated in the database?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here is the code:-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ReviewService {
    @Autowired
    public ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public reviews createReview(String reviewBody, String imdbId) {
        reviews review = reviewRepository.insert(new reviews(reviewBody));

        mongoTemplate.update(movie.class)
                .matching(Criteria.where("imdbId").is(imdbId))
                .apply(new Update().push("reviewIds").value(review))
                .first();

        return review;
    }
}
```